# Display underline letter in TabPage text in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I was trying to display an underline letter in a control text using `&` as found in article : [Create Access Key For Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-create-access-keys?view=netdesktop-5.0).

When implemented on label, it worked fine. When tried on Tabpage text, it did not work as expected.

> (please refer screenshot)

[image: Screenshot]

Below is the code I have written:

**Working One:**

```
label1.Text = "Form "+ "&Loaded";
tabPage1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9.25f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)0);
```

**Not Working One:**

```
tabPage1.Text = "Field &One";
tabPage1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9.25f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)0);
```

`&` is displayed as it is, in `TabPage` text.

Kindly suggest what am I missing.

Comment: same works fine in visual basic

Comment: Google says it's impossible. You have to make your own tab control.

Comment: Here is a custom control: [MnemonicTabControl - a tabcontrol with accelerator key support (Codeproject)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12011/MnemonicTabControl-a-tabcontrol-with-accelerator-k). Perhaps the [Kryton Navigator](https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton). Or any other libre or commercial controls.

Answer (score 0):

From the fine manual:

> Controls that cannot receive focus can't have access keys, except label controls.

I recall reading somewhere that focusing in tabpages is unusual (focus events fire not when the page itself changes focus but when items within it do), and I don't think the tab is actually part of the TabPage, but part of the TabControl that holds the page..